# Limit shipping address of a group of products to certain country in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have to limit the shipping address of music and dvds to only one country in Magento. For example a client has in basket 3 books and a dvd and he selects a country other than allowed, I need a message to be shown: "You have in your basket at least one music or movie product. Distribution rights are limited only to /country/".
Does anybody know a quick way to do this?

Comment: You should post what you are trying so others can help you. Like code, database design, etc...

Comment: It's magento. Sorry I only tagged it. Will correct my fault immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not cheap the [Product Matrix Shipping](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1357/product-matrix-shipping) should be capable of providing this.

Comment: It's not cheap at all :|
I'm rather interested in a free, simple solution. I'm ready to hardcode something in theme, but I need this to be solved. The question would be how to check selected country and where?